# Three.js model loading causing the browser temporary freeze

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been using Three.JS lib in the past few week for loading an animated 3d model.
The model & texture source files were originally .obj and .mtl, and sized approximately 60 MB.

As you can imagine the loading time was pretty long and in addition the loading caused a freeze. 
In an attempt to speed up things I converted the model to binary, and the objects sizes are now 15MB~. Loading time is now faster but it still freezes.

What i've tried so far to solve the freeze:

- Web Workers - doesn't seem to be it, [reference](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2215)
- Convert to JSON and use the native loader
- Convert to binary
- Progress Bar - wasn't of any help

this is the loading part of the code:

```
        this.loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
        this.showPreloader();
        this.loader.load(jsPath, function (geometry, material) {
            var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(material));
            this.scene.add(object);
            this.hidePreloader();

            if (typeof cb === 'function') {
                cb();
            }
        }.bind(this));
```

any ideas?

Comment: You can use Chrome CPU profiling to see if any JavaScript method is blocking in the main thread: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: I don't have code for you so I'm not giving a full answer, but I know that http://openctm.sourceforge.net/ has been used successfully in WebGL to significantly shrink model sizes down. They went from 85MB .obj to 1.5MB .ctm

Comment: Does the freeze still happen if you don't call `this.showPreloader()` ?

Comment: @Leeft, The OpenCTM blender plugin is not supported anymore, and OpenCTM doesn't seem to compile under ubuntu newer versions.. Do you know any other ways to convert?

Comment: Get a windows VM from modern.ie (they expire after 3 months, then you need to rebuild or restore the snapshot made before first boot) and run it on Windows that way maybe? (assuming you don't have access to a windows box).

Comment: @Leeft, thanks for the answer! I tried that and succeeded loading the model. Problem is I'm not able to attach my .mtl file to it. Do you know a way?